# can I use another thread to perform a long term operation in BroadcastReceiver.onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

about the BroadcastReceiver.onReceive,the android docs says: 
If this BroadcastReceiver was    launched through a  tag, then the object is no longer alive after returning  from this function.
    But my test code says different thing.

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            **System.out.println("thread in:" + System.currentTimeMillis());**
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            **System.out.println("thread finish:"
                    + System.currentTimeMillis());**
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

It will print both thread in and thread finish,seems like I can use another thread in onReceive.

Comment: what u want to ask..

Comment: I want to know evevybody says do not run another thread of long term operation,because broadcastreceiver is no longer alive after returning from the onReceive function.But my test code says different,It can run a long term operation in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can run use another thread in broadcast receiver. broadcast receiver onRecieve() method runs in UI main thread . So onRecieve must not take a lot of time in execution. 
Generally starting a service is usually a better approach than to start a thread .however you may have other reason to use a thread in broadcast receiver.So its perfectly ok to use.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, new thread was used to create to handle the task. The thread will continue to run but the receiver will be terminated after you finish the `OnReceive()`.

Noted there's no guarantee how long you thread could survive. The system could be under memory pressure and remove your process right away, and the `print` will never be executed.

The right way to do this is to start an foreground service, which will give your process higher priority.

Answer (score -2):

Yes..you can use multiple thread in broadcast receiver onReceive() method;

Comment: everyone include the android docs say if you want to run a long term operation in broadcastreceiver,you should start a service to do it instead of run another thread,because the broadcastreceiver object would die after returning from onReive.